# Meaning of WCF counters in perfmon.exe

Tags: wcf, perfmon

I would like to use PerfMon.exe to monitor the calls to a WCF service, but I don't understand which counter I have to use. I tried Calls and Instance but the result is always 0.
Could you explain me the meaning of counters?
Moreover, there are 3 groups of counters:

- ServiceModelEndpoint
- ServiceModelOperation
- ServiceModelService

What is their meaning?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Service can be exposed via many endpoints. A service can contain many operations.

Which counters you choose depends on what you want to monitor.

For example:

- Are you interested in how many times the http endpoint is called
- Are you interested in how many times the TakeMoneyOutOfABankAccount is called
- Are you interested in how many times the SecurityService is called

For details see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx